# PYAUTOGUI переодически перестаёт нажимать

Tags: python, pyautogui

Здравствуйте я недавно столкнулся с проблемой, я автоматизирую нажатия в эмулятора распознавая кнопки на экране. Проблема заключается в том что когда я использую `pyautogui.click()` изредка он не кликает, наводит на иконку но не кликает. Потом эта проблема так же фантомно исчезает, что мне делать что бы такого не было?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том что pyautogui не кликал без прав администратора, запуск кода от админа решила проблему